# MSMerge_contents Table Populated After One Sync

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am running merge replication with SQL 2012.

When I first create my publication the MSMerge_contents table is populated with a large number of records with the colv1 being set to 0xFF.

When I run the stored procedure like this,

```
sp_showcolv @colv =0xFF
```

It becomes apparent that these records do not represent actual changes to the underlying records, unless I am missing something?

Why are those records there? Is it because of partitioning, or column level tracking? I am using column level tracking, but am wondering whether I need to revisit this option?